# sample_n dynamically based on category

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with two columns `ID` and `category`.  From this dataframe I take a sample of 3 from each category, and from that sample, I take a subsample of 6 from the total to get `sub_df` a dataframe with 6 elements.

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:100, category = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 100, replace = T))
head(df)
#    ID category
#  1  1        C
#  2  2        H
#  3  3        E
#  4  4        I
#  5  5        J
#  6  6        A

sub_df <- df %>% group_by(category) %>% sample_n(3) %>% ungroup() %>% sample_n(6)
sub_df
#  # A tibble: 6 x 2
#       ID category
#    <int> <fct>   
#  1    72 G       
#  2    88 I       
#  3    24 J       
#  4    33 G       
#  5    86 E       
#  6    27 F
```

I would  like to `sample_n` from the original dataframe `df` again.  However, this time `n` is dependent on the count of each category in the `sub_df` dataframe.

```r
sub_df %>% count(category)
#  A tibble: 5 x 2
#   category     n
#   <fct>    <int>
# 1 E            1
# 2 F            1
# 3 G            2
# 4 I            1
# 5 J            1
```

For each group that is *not* represented in `sub_df`, I would like to sample 3 from `df` just like above.  However, for those categories that are included in `sub_df` I would like to sample `3-n`times to get a total number of 3 samples across all categories if the resulting dataframe is combined with `sub_df`.  So in this example, E,F,I,J would all have 2 samples, and G would just need 1.

I'm thinking I could loop through each category and do a sample based on count of each category in `sub_df`.  However, as the number of categories gets extremely large, this loop could take a significant amount of time.  I was hoping there might be a tidier way to do this.

The resulting counts would look like so:

```r
result_df %>% count(category)
#  A tibble: 10 x 2
#    category     n
#    <fct>    <int>
#  1 A            3
#  2 B            3
#  3 C            3
#  4 D            3
#  5 E            2
#  6 F            2
#  7 G            1
#  8 H            3
#  9 I            2
# 10 J            2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr` and `purrr`. The idea is to first create data frame `df_s2` showing the new number of samples for each category, split `df` into `df_list` by category, and apply the `sample_n` function over the `df_list` and the number in `df_s2`.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:100, category = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 100, replace = T))
sub_df <- df %>% group_by(category) %>% sample_n(3) %>% ungroup() %>% sample_n(6)

library(purrr)

# Create a table to store the sample number, default to 3
df_s <- data_frame(category = unique(df$category),
                   Number = 3)

# Minus the count number in sub_df
df_s2 <- df_s %>%
  left_join(sub_df %>% count(category), by = "category") %>%
  mutate(n = ifelse(is.na(n), 0, n)) %>%
  mutate(Number = Number - n) %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  arrange(category)

# Split the df by category
df_list <- split(df, f = df$category)

# Apply the sample function on df_list based on df_s2
result_df <- map2_dfr(df_list, df_s2$Number, ~sample_n(.x, .y))

# Check the count number of result_df
result_df %>% count(category)
# # A tibble: 10 x 2
#    category     n
#    <fct>    <int>
#  1 A            3
#  2 B            3
#  3 C            3
#  4 D            3
#  5 E            2
#  6 F            2
#  7 G            1
#  8 H            3
#  9 I            2
# 10 J            2
```